# Need to order column data in CSV files to match the Row 1 header, but only move the row 2 and below data

Tags: python, excel, csv, sorting, columnsorting

I am stuck on an issue in which I have a CSV file and need to keep all the headers in row 1 in the specific order I was given, but the row 2 and below data for some of the columns are displaced meaning in Column C I will need to move that column of data excluding row 1 header to Column F. I looked through stackoverflow and found solutions in python, but those solutions move the entire columns in order, but my goal here is to move only the data in the columns to different columns while leaving the row headers exactly where they are originally.

Please note that I am not allowed to use Excel to easily move the data over, but instead will need to work with just a common CSV file.

## A B C D

## 4 1 10 7

## 5 2 11 8

## 6 3 12 9

For example, I will need to keep the Column headers in row 1 in the exact same order, but rearrange the data in rows 2-4 from Column B to Column A and the Data from Column D to Column C.

Comment: Just adding a bit extra for an example. I want to swap the column data while leaving the row 1 headers in the exact same place. For example if I have four columns headers: Shoes, Shirts, Pants, Belts - if all my Shoes data is in the Pants column then I will need to move the row 2 and below column data for Pants into the Shoes column.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_csv("csv file path")

# swap Col A and Col B 
df['F'] = df['A']
df['A'] = df['B']
df['B'] = df['F']

# swap Col C and Col D
df['F'] = df['C']
df['C'] = df['D']
df['D'] = df['F']

df.drop('F', axis=1) # Delete Temp Col
```

I guess you mean that?

Comment: Hi Leochen, I want to swap the column data while leaving the row 1 headers in the exact same place. For example if I have four columns headers: Shoes, Shirts, Pants, Belts - if all my Shoes data is in the Pants column then I will need to move the row 2 and below column data for Pants into the Shoes column.